# selecting last 10 distinct rows with subqueries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I want to select the last 10 rows from my `messages` table that have either the `receiver_id = 1` or the `sender_id = 1` but those which have the `receiver_id = 1` have `DISTICT` applied on the `sender_id` and those which have the `sender_id = 1` have the `DISTINCT` property applied on the `receiver_id`.

Basically, what am I trying to say is that I want to select the very last 10 messages either sent either received by the user with the id of 1, sent to or sent by 10 different other users.

What have i tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT sender_id FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = 1) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) tmp ORDER BY id ASC

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * DISTINCT receiver_id FROM messages WHERE sender_id= 1) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) tmp ORDER BY id ASC
```

But trying to get the separately and adding the arrays (and sorting them by the ids of the messages) didn't quite work.

So I tried making a query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT receiver_id, sender_id FROM messages WHERE (receiver_id = 1 OR sender_id = 1)) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) tmp ORDER BY id ASC
```

but it turned out my query is a total mess and, of corse, doesn't return me what I wanted.

P.S.: I am using XAMPP MySQL: MariaDB

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  `DISTINCT` isn't a property and it is unclear what you intend by that requirement.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Your second paragraph is:

> Basically, what am I trying to say is that I want to select the 10
>   very last messages (rows) stored in the database that were either sent
>   or received by the user with the id of 1.

This is a fairly basic query:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m
WHERE 1 IN (m.receiver_id, m.sender_id)
ORDER BY m.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: I don't know how to explain what I want =))
I guess I'll edit my question when I find a way to explain this properly

Comment: Ooh.. I think this is what I wanted to ask for:
I want the last 10 messages, either sent either received by the user with the id of 1, sent to or sent by 10 different other users.
I'll edit my question now.